# Is it possible to encrypt data with a GPG public key that doesn't have the encryption usage flag set?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I have received a public key that does not appear to have the encryption capability enabled:

```
> gpg --list-keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/Users/me/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2016-09-15 [SC]
      C931D34D20D3D9BF0649197487CC91EBC4928E69
uid           [ unknown] Application Support <application.support@company.example.com>
```

When I attempt to use it to encrypt a file, GnuPG returns an error:

```
> gpg -v -r C931D34D20D3D9BF0649197487CC91EBC4928E69 --encrypt myfile                                                                                                                                                                                                               12:43:37
gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.
gpg: C931D34D20D3D9BF0649197487CC91EBC4928E69: skipped: Unusable public key
gpg: myfile: encryption failed: Unusable public key
```

There are no encryption subkeys available on this public key I have. And yet the person that holds the private key is able to receive encrypted files from other parties and decrypt them (using the matched private key).

What could explain this? Is it possible to force GnuPG (or an equivalent) to encrypt using the public key, even when the usage flag is not set to do so?

Comment: You can force GnuPG to do this. I'm not sure how though. Probably in the manual.